# Help inputting words into Swype

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, keyboard, swype

On my old phone (still the Samsung galaxy s 3) I was somehow able to input the "words" 'c:' ';D' and other things like that with symbols at the beginning or end into its dictionary. That old phone broke, and I wasn't able to transfer that dictionary into my new phone. Now I'm unable to enter those into the dictionary because it won't select the symbol. Is there anything I can do about this?